# Why does it keep ending

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am coding something in Sublime Text:

```
from tkinter import * 
newscr = Tk()
newscr.geometry("350x350")
newscr.title("Welcome to software!")
def login():
    print("Login session started! <3")
def register():
  print("Registration session started! <3")
  passwo = StringVar()
  s = Tk()
  s.geometry("269x200")
  s.title("Login!")
  yes = Label(s, text="Username:")
  yes.place(x=100, y=50)
  no = Label(s, text="Password:")
  no.place(x=100, y=70)
  okden = Label(s,text="Please enter your\n credentials here").place(x=130, y=5)
  Su = Entry(s, width=15, textvariable=user).place(x=169, y=50)
  Sv = Entry(s, width=15, textvariable=passwo).place(x=169, y=70)
  s.mainloop()
  labeluno = Label(newscr, text="Login to Software. \n Don't have an account?\n Sign 
up!").place(x=130, y=30)
B1 = Button(newscr, text="Login", command=login).place(x=175, y=85)
B2 = Button(newscr, text="Register", command=register).place(x=175, y=120)

newscr.mainloop()
```

But when i run it, it does this:
Finished in 0.4 seconds
The code just ends itself and I don't know why!
help me

Comment: Works for me in the standard python IDLE. I see the two buttons and the second one opens a new Tk() instance.

Check your Sublime Text settings?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is broken because there is a line break inside the string in

```
 labeluno = Label(newscr, text="Login to Software. \n Don't have an account?\n Sign 
up!").place(x=130, y=30)
```

Your IDE should indicate you that, as it is a straight out syntax error. Otherwise, you should be able to see the error message in a terminal, or on the IDE itself upon running your program.
**It is very important** that you locate the error message, and learn to read it, otherwise it won't be possible for you to do any useful programming. Not even seasoned developers can know that a program is right all the time, when it breaks, the error message usually tells what the problem was.

Besides this problem:

You should not neither create 2 `Tk` instances and much less call twice `tkinter.mainloop()`.

Once you call `mainloop`, tkinter is already in control of your program, and all of your code that will run is by callbacks.

For creating the second window, instead of  `Tk` call `TopLevel` (and pass you `newscr` as the first argument).

Also, when you create a widget and call `.place` or other method on it imediattelly, the return value you get is that of the call to `place`, not of the widget creation. This is the value `None`. That means that lines like:

`Su = Entry(s, width=15, textvariable=user).place(x=169, y=50)`

are storing nothing of use in the  `Su` variable. You have to do that in 2 steps:

```
Su = Entry(s, width=15, textvariable=user)
Su.place(x=169, y=50)
```

Now `Su` contains a reference to your widget.